# PhantomJS altenatives?

Tags: browser, phantomjs

Does anybody know if there's any alternative for PhantomJS? I need headless page processing with JS support. Fast and lightweight. PhantomJS is quite hungry to the resources, consumes lots of memory and CPU while processing pages. I wonder if there's something more efficient with similar capabilities, some engine based on WebKit or similar. Or maybe some approach to run browser instance and manage it in VM?
Thanks!

Comment: [SlimerJS](https://slimerjs.org/) is not bad

Comment: PhantomJS is just a wrapper around the Webkit engine. It consumes as much resources as it needs to do what it does.

Comment: Slimer J's is gecko, has a lot of the support for modern JS that Phantom (generally using older versions of webkit) is lagging on implementing. Both will require as many resources as those engines require to operate your site/app. Both can run headless via cli.

Answer (score 1):

Since Chrome supports now (as of version 59) headless running, there's no reason any more to use outdated PhantomJS. Unless you cannot update/install chrome on target machine. If you have included e.g. karma-chrome-launcher in karma.conf you can now just specify:

```
browsers = ['ChromeHeadless']
```

There's also possibility to use ChromeCanary or ChromeCanaryHeadless.